# app crash on importing greater than 8 megapixel Image to uiimageview

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-management, uiimageview, ios8.1

Our App crashing on importing images greater than 8 `megapixels` on `iPhone`. At times high memory usage too.

By the way images that we are trying to import are greater than 8 megapixels and not that huge too `4000 x 3000` (12 megapixel).Photos taken using `iPhone` Camera are `3264 x 2448` (8 megapixels).

Here is our MEMORY REPORT

when importing 8 megapixel image

[image]

---

when importing 12 megapixel image

[image]

Huge difference in memory usage. Anyone have any idea why there's huge difference in memory usage and any solution of this?

(we'll be using the images to edit,filter,process etc).

Here is our code

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *selectedImage=[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    //SCALING UIIMAGE

    UIImage *scaledImage=[[UIImage alloc]init];
    if ((selectedImage.size.width>3264) && (selectedImage.size.height>2448))
    {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(selectedImage.size.width/2, selectedImage.size.height/2), NO, 0.0);
        NSLog(@" HEIGHT %f",selectedImage.size.height);
        NSLog(@" WIDTH %f",selectedImage.size.width);

        [selectedImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0,selectedImage.size.width/2 ,selectedImage.size.height/2 )];
       scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        NSLog(@" HEIGHT %f",scaledImage.size.height);
        NSLog(@" WIDTH %f",scaledImage.size.width);


        VisualEffectImageVIew.image=scaledImage;
        BackgroundImageView.image=scaledImage;
        ForegroundImageView.image=scaledImage;
    }
    else
    {
    VisualEffectImageVIew.image=selectedImage;
    BackgroundImageView.image=selectedImage;
    ForegroundImageView.image=selectedImage;
    }
   if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else
    {


        [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

        [self popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:popoverController];
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

_MGL9114.jpg is a image file.

_MGL9114 size is 3744px × 5616px

If I import this file into my iOS project and render it in UIView.It would take 108MB memory.Because iOS would render UIImage in realtime,if your image is high quality,it would use high memory to cache image data.

If you want to reduce it,you should load UIImage in backend and output a compressed version. It just take 23MB memory.

Even if you want to edit the image,just render the effect on compressed version.When the users complete their edit,you process all effects in backend(don't render the original version) and save the original version to user's library.

```
NSString * imageBundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"_MGL9114" ofType:@"jpg"];
NSData * imageData = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:imageBundle];
UIImage * handleImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(handleImage.size.width/10, handleImage.size.height/10), NO, 0.0);
[handleImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0,handleImage.size.width/10 ,handleImage.size.height/10 )];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


UIImageView * imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, handleImage.size.width/10, handleImage.size.height/10)];
[imageView setImage:newImage];

[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

Comment: Resizing all images would be problem because some might be very small too ,in this case how to check image resolution and resize them if they are large so that they use less memory?

Comment: After loading your image from bundle,you can get imageData.Set UIImage with NSData.Now you can get size of the image.

Comment: handleImage.size.width,handleImage.size.height. :-)

Comment: We have edited the question and  included code  please see it.

Comment: @USERX2DX Yes you have got "selectedImage".You already get selectedImage.size.If the image is too large,just resize it.

Comment: See our updated code .The image scaling is working,but we are still receiving memory warnings and app crashes.

Comment: VisualEffectImageVIew,BackgroundImageView,ForegroundImageView.All of these views are displayed in the same time?Why?Besides,selectedImage.size.width/2 is still be large.As we can see,iPhone 6 Plus's screen is 1920px * 1080px.If your Image's width is 1080 and not allow users to scale the view,users can hardly see the details.

Comment: yes all those image views are displayed in one view but that's not a problem ,because app uses more memory and at time crashes when executing this code  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(handleImage.size.width/10, handleImage.size.height/10), NO, 0.0); [handleImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0,handleImage.size.width/10 ,handleImage.size.height/10 )];

Comment: @USERX2DX Did you try "UIImageJPEGRepresentation(yourImage,0.1)" to compress your image?

Comment: No, that just reduces the file size

Comment: @USERX2DX You can try to use it.